# vertical alignment of minipages in two columns in a longtable

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, longtable, minipage

I began to learn latex and I use it to prepare a CV. I made good experiences by organizing my CV with a longtable, in order to define the widths and the alignments of the different text
blocks.

In my example the longtable consists of only one row and two columns. Further more, each cell holds a minipage, themselves holding another tabular.

The minipages in both columns somehow influence each other.
The more lines I am inserting in the right table, the farther down the left minipage is moving.
Of course I want the minipages in both columns longtable to be
fixed at the very top. This only happens when using tabular in the minipage. Using normal text, the minipages remain at the top.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\RequirePackage[quiet]{fontspec}
    \newfontfamily\body[]{HelveticaNeue-Light}
    \newfontfamily\thinfont[]{HelveticaNeue-Light}
    \newfontfamily\bold[]{HelveticaNeue-Medium}
    \newfontfamily\headingfont[]{Helvetica Neue}
    \newfontfamily\ultralight[]{HelveticaNeue-UltraLight}
    \setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Color=textcolor]{HelveticaNeue-Light}

\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
     a4paper,
     total={210mm,297mm},
     left=0mm,
     right=0mm,
     top=0mm,
     bottom=20mm,
     }

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{soul}


\usepackage{colortbl}
    \definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.4}
    \definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{102,204,0}
    \definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{64,64,64}
    \definecolor{mybluetwo}{RGB}{222,231,241}
    \definecolor{myred}{RGB}{144,53,41}

%outer longtable
    \newcolumntype{A}{>{}p{0.15\paperwidth}}
    \newcolumntype{B}{>{}p{0.70\paperwidth}}    

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
%Headline
    \noindent\fcolorbox{myblue}{myblue}{%
    \begin{minipage}[c][4cm]{\paperwidth}
    \sodef\spaceout{}{0.25em}{0.9em}{1pt}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{c}
            %\Huge\textcolor{mygreen}{{\makebox[\linewidth][c]{\ultralight\spaceout{Firstname}\bold\spaceout{ name}}}}\\
            \Huge\textcolor{mygreen}{\ultralight firstname \bold name}\\
            \textcolor{mygreen}{* * *} \\
            \Large\textcolor{mygreen}{\ultralight curriculum vitae}\\
            \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
    \end{minipage}}%

\begin{longtable}{|A|B|}
    \fbox{
    \begin{minipage}[t][6cm]{0.14\paperwidth}
        \begin{tabular}{|p{0.12\paperwidth}|}
            Left Table\\
            left Table\\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}}
    &
    \fbox{
    \begin{minipage}[t][16cm]{0.69\paperwidth}
        \begin{tabular}{|p{0.66\paperwidth}|}
            Right Table\\
            Right Table\\
            Right Table\\
            Right Table\\
            Right Table\\
            Right Table\\
            Right Table\\
            Right Table\\
            Right Table\\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}}
    \\
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Are you aware there's a number of packages dedicated to CVs?

Comment: Thank you very much for your hint. In fact, there are plenty of ready prepared CVs. Anyhow, for me prepareing the CV is the perfect opportunity to get into latex. For me, learning works best when it serves a purpose. Thus, I am going the hard way and try to prepare one myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `[t]` positioning specifier not only to the `minipage` environments, but to both `tabular` environments as well.

[image]

```
%% preamble stuff omitted
\begin{longtable}{|A|B|}
    \fbox{
    \begin{minipage}[t][6cm]{0.14\paperwidth}
        \begin{tabular}[t]{|p{0.12\paperwidth}|} % <--- "[t]" is new
            Left Table\\
            left Table\\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}}
    &
    \fbox{
    \begin{minipage}[t][16cm]{0.69\paperwidth}
        \begin{tabular}[t]{|p{0.66\paperwidth}|} % <--- "[t]" is new
            Right Table\\
            Right Table\\
            Right Table\\
            Right Table\\
            Right Table\\
            Right Table\\
            Right Table\\
            Right Table\\
            Right Table\\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}}
    \\
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: Perfectly correct. Thank you so much. As always, 4 eyes see more than two.